# How to change interface strucure and rename all references in VS Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an interface

```
interface IApplicationState {
    config: IConfig;
    lang: ILang;
    //many others
}
```

Currently is used in many places like in classes with `connect` from `react-redux`, or in reducers method like:

```
const setLangReducer = (state: IApplicationState , { lang }: { lang: LangType }): IApplicationState  => ({
    ...state,
    lang: {
        currentLang: lang
    }
});
```

I want to add some fileds inside at the root level, and all existing move down as children for new property e.g.:

```
interface IApplicationState {
    generalConfigs: {
        config: IConfig;
        lang: ILang;
    };
    externalConfig: {
        domain: string;         
    }
}
```

If I make change manually, I will must to fix all references for `config` and `lang` from root to `generalConfigs.config` and `generalConfigs.lang`

maybe is there some automatically options to change all references by changing interface structure?

Comment: You can write a codemod to do that: https://www.toptal.com/javascript/write-code-to-rewrite-your-code

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change all of the names you need to press ctrl and then 3 times R

Comment: the question is for Visual Studio Code, maybe you mean renaming in Visual Studio. But in Visual Studio Code, Ctrl+R, is Navigate between recently opened folders and workspaces#
Open Recent

Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+R


Displays a Quick Pick dropdown with the list from File > Open Recent with recently opened folders and workspaces followed by files.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).